# How to speed up execution of this function?

Tags: performance-tuning

How can I speed up the execution of following function, specifically for larger values of n?

```
f[n_, 0, s_, a_] := 1
fr[n_, s_] := fr[n, s] = Sum[N[m^-s], {m, 1, n}]
f[n_, 1, s_, a_] := f[n, 1, s, a] = fr[Floor[n], s] - fr[a, s]
f[n_, k_, s_, a_] := 
 f[n, k, s, a] = 
  N[Sum[Binomial[k, j] (m^-s)^j f[Floor[n/(m^j)], k - j, s, m], {j,
  1, k}, {m, a + 1, Floor[n^(1/k)]}]]
```

For reference, n, k, and a should all be positive integers. s should be any complex number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be somewhat faster. I use `N[]` or equivalent thereof in some places. Also removed a `Floor` since the argument had to be integral anyway.

```
Clear[f, fr]
f[n_, 0, s_, a_] := 1
fr[n_, s_] := fr[n, s] = Sum[m^-s, {m, 1., n}]
f[n_, 1, s_, a_] := f[n, 1, s, a] = fr[n, s] - fr[a, s]
f[n_, k_, s_, a_] := 
 f[n, k, s, a] = 
  N[Sum[Binomial[k, j] (N[m]^-s)^j f[Floor[n/(N[m]^j)], k - j, s, 
      m], {j, 1, k}, {m, a + 1., Floor[N[n]^(1./k)]}]]
```

There may be further improvements to be had but this could at least be a start.

Comment: Isn't `HarmonicNumber[n, s]//N` faster than `Sum[m^-s, {m, 1., n}]`?

Comment: With its current hat your avatar remembers me a few Star Trek episodes :)

Comment: @belisarius (1) `harmonicNumber is almost certainly a better way to go. I failed to see that simplification. (2) I also had that impression of the hat. What can I say? I get sent them from SE Central and I just put them on for a few days.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I can just about picture you as the scientific officer from Vulfram.

Comment: @Yves Klett When I was younger I kept long hair to hide my pointy ears (they receded with age).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau way to *go*,  Legolas!

Comment: @Yves Klett That's "Dr. Legolas", to you.